# Import images with vite in laravel

Tags: laravel, vite

I'm trying to get Vite to recognize my images but without success, in the blade I use the directive {{ Vite::images("path_image") }} and everything works perfectly but in my js file it doesn't find the images, below is the snippet of the image call in the js file, this is being loaded via jquery and the image itself comes from a database, how could I get Vite to recognize these images? Thanks, I'm using laravel with laravel-vite-plugin

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Comment: search_result += ` <img src="${value['templates'][b]['id'] == template_selected ? value['templates'][b]['layouts']['thumb'] : ''}" class="thumb-theme" />`